# Passing a ViewModel to a Partial View call in the Layout.cshtml

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

**BACKGROUND**

I am trying to make use of Dashboard template on an MVC application I'm working on.

[image: WebArch Template]

I am not sure how I can pass a ViewModel to the top bar I've called Header.

**CODE**

In my `_Layout.cshtml`, I have split the HTML like so:

```
<body class="">
  @Html.Partial("_Header")

  <div class="page-container row-fluid">
    @Html.Partial("_Sidebar")

    <div class="page-content">
      <div class="content">
        @RenderBody()
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

I am guessing this is wrong because now I cannot pass a ViewModel to the header section, or if I can, we're not supposed to?

What is the right way of splitting this?

Comment: You can simply add a model as a parameter to the `Partial` call e.g. `@Html.Partial("_Header", SomeModel);`

Comment: That would mean I would have to tie my `_Layout.cshtml` to a model no?

Comment: Oh my bad, I didn't realize you were in the `_Layout.cshtml` file. @StephenMuecke's answer is correct.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ASP.NET MVC How to use PartialView in Layout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31410586/asp-net-mvc-how-to-use-partialview-in-layout)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of `@Html.Partial()`, use `@Html.Action()` or `@{ Html.RenderAction(); }` to call a `[ChildActionOnly]` controller methods that initializes your model for the dashboard and returns a partial view, for example

```
[ChildActionOnly]
public PartialViewResult Header()
{
    // initialize a model
    return PartialView("_Header", model)
}
```

and in the layout

```
@{ Html.RenderAction("Header", yourControllerName); }
```

The alternative is that the model you use in each view using that layout would need a property which is the model used to generate your dashboard and then use `@Html.Partial("_Header", Model.yourDashBoardProperty)`